# Importing from another module throws error

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, import, redux

I am receiving an error "Unexpected token {" when using the command:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
```

I have node 11 installed, and I assume it supports the import funcionality? Or is it that destructuring itself is not supported in node?

Answer (score 2):

ES6 Import/Export is not supported on node yet. You have two solutions here:

1. Use require: `const { createStore } = require('redux');`
2. Use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) or another package to enable import/export. I invite to read this to have a better understanding: [Setting a minimal environment for ES6](https://dev.to/aurelkurtula/setting-up-a-minimal-node-environment-with-webpack-and-babel--1j04), [Import/Export in node with ESM](https://medium.com/@jamischarles/using-import-export-in-node-js-with-esm-7ce9153ff63)